# basic slider to change variable in visual c++

Tags: c++, slider

I'm trying to modify an existing program.  Every time I try to find a tutorial on sliders in visual c++ or look at the code it always brings up the mfc class wizard which doesn't pop or take me to an automatically made event since the program is already made I guess?

I need an example of like the simplest program to create a slider which changes an integer variable in visual c++.  Also how do you set the limits of the slider.  For instance I know pixel bender, and in that's it's super simple you just declare:

```
 parameter int three60
    <
        minValue:0;
        maxValue:50;
        defaultValue:40;
    >;
```

What would be the analog of this in vs c++?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the basic functions to set the position of sliders here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760221(v=vs.85).aspx

I found it through someone calling the sliders scrollbars, i guess the functionality is pretty much the same, and was able to find a pretty decent simple tutorial on that, but still really difficult to find any mfc class wizardless tut or explaining nub wise how all these functions work exactly, still lost.

This site seems like it's becoming fairly useless to nubs that have legit questions, everyone just downvotes you immediately. sigh

Found a bunch of stuff under "trackbar" thanks to a friend... why can't they be consistent with the names!